# How to stop pigpio daemon from running at system start

Tags: pigpio

I wish to use the pigpio C library which requires that the daemon is not running. My application will be in an embedded standalone system and I cannot therefore kill the daemon.

Comment: What did you do to have it autostart in the first place? That is important to know. Cron (as described here) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=103752

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how it was started in the first place:

1. If it was started as a service on Raspbian use the following command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl disable pigpiod
   ```
2. Assuming you followed [this description](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=103752) to add pigpiod to the crontab:

   ```
   @reboot              /usr/local/bin/pigpiod
   ```

   simply use `sudo crontab -e` again to remove this line and have it not started on reboot.